# Pass context to axiosInstance Nextjs

Tags: next.js, cookies, axios, server-side-rendering

I using `Nextjs@13.0.6`.

I have a `axiosInstance`:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import webStorageClient from '@/utils/webStorageClient';

import { API_SERVER, REFRESH_TOKEN } from '@/settings/constants';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_SERVER,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  timeout: 600000,
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    return config;
  },
  function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response: any) => {
    return response?.data;
  },
  (error: any) => {
    const { config, response } = error;
    const originalRequest = config;

    if (response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;

      const tokenRefresh = webStorageClient.get(REFRESH_TOKEN);

      // Refresh the token
      return axiosInstance
        .post('/token/refresh/', { refresh: tokenRefresh })
        .then((res: any) => {
          // Update the token in the headers
          axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common[
            'Authorization'
          ] = `Bearer ${res?.access}`;
          originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${res?.access}`;
          webStorageClient.setToken(res?.access);
          // Repeat the original request with the updated headers
          return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
        });
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

The `const tokenRefresh = webStorageClient.get(REFRESH_TOKEN);` is get refresh token in client, it work well. But in server side how can I get cookie in `axiosInstance`?

`Nextjs@13.0.6` need context to access cookie, etc... in server side, so how can I pass **context** to `axiosInstance`?

Comment: You can access request cookies inside [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware) with req.cookies although I'm not sure how useful this will be in your case